# Can quick sort time complexity be $\Theta(n\sqrt n)$ for some inputs?

Tags: time-complexity, quicksort

I know that the time complexity of quick sort in the worst case is $\Theta(n^2)$ and in the average case is $\Theta(n \log n)$. Can it be $\Theta(n\sqrt n)$ for certain inputs?

Comment: In the average case it's $\Theta(n\log n)$. It can probably be $\Theta(n\sqrt{n})$ for certain inputs of a certain structure. I suggest looking up the best and worst cases for quicksort, and trying to combine them.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the array is sorted. If you always pick the element at n/2 as pivot then the time is O(n log n). If you always pick the first or last element it’s $O(n^2)$.

So which pivot gives you $O(n^{1.5})$?

Comment: The third quarter?

Comment: Can you give a formal proof?

Comment: This answer is very much incomplete. And misleading too, for any constant $c$, if you always pick the element at $cn$ as your pivot the complexity is $\Theta(n \log n)$, and never $\Theta(n\sqrt n)$.

Comment: orlp, how is this misleading? Obviously picking the element at index cn for fixed 0 < c < n will not lead to Theta(n^(3/2)). So that is not the answer. But there is a simple answer. And finding that simple answers helps you understanding how likely / unlikely this case is.